# How to increase the column reference by one column when copying a formula vertically?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data table containing integers:

[image: Data table]

I need to evaluate the numbers of times a 1 appears in a column and the results
need to be in presented in a column vertically. Thus for column A the count = 0, for column B = 1, for column C = 2 etc and should be presented as follows;

```
0
1
2
3 ...etc
```

Therefore the column reference is incremented by one (A > B > C >D etc).

Using the formula countif, I can manually do this for a single column. My problem is that I have hundreds of columns and need to copy the formula vertically downwards whilst maintaining the row reference, but incrementing the columns reference by one.

I have a tried a combination of Countif() and Offset() but to no avail.

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2;0;0;5;1);1)
```

This produces the correct result for one column, but as I copy downwards, the column "A"stays the same. This need to be as follows:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1;0;0;5;1);1)
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1;0;0;5;1);1)
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(C1;0;0;5;1);1) etc
```

If anyone can help. I would be grateful.

Comment: please post the exact formulas you've tried and explain how exactly they give wrong results. Also have a look on [absolute and relative references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX to set the range:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($A$1:$AAA$5,0,ROW(1:1)),1)
```

Set the `$AAA` to the last column with data.  Put in the first column and copy/drag down.

[image]